# 18.04: Need to add settings for Wacom Intuos Pro tablet

Tags: settings, wacom

I recently bought a [Wacom Intuos Pro](https://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-tablets/wacom-intuos-pro) and tried to use it with Xubuntu 18.04 and found that there was no settings or any graphical aids to help with tweaking settings. So I decided to install Ubuntu 18.04 on top of my current instillation (So now I can swap between Ubuntu and Xubuntu Desktops as I please.). But when I went into settings, there was no "Wacom Tablet" option under devices.

[picture of settings page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmJM0.png)

I'm not sure if its possible to add this in without reinstalling, but if I can I'd really like to.

Thanks in advance! :)

Edit: I installed the ubuntu desktop using

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

and then just selected ubuntu when logging in.
also, the kernal version is 4.15.9-88-generic.

running

```
lsusb -v
```

gave an output too long to provide.

Comment: 1) It may be relevant; which of the five models did you get? There's a different Bluetooth mode.... See https://www.wacom.com/en-us/products/pen-tablets/wacom-intuos-pro#Specifications . 2) What does Setting show for the Mouse? 3) Also, when you run `lsusb -v` please copy the result then come back here, click [edit] and paste the result into the question. Please don't put it into Comments as that loses the formatting.

Comment: "*install Ubuntu 18.04 on top of my current*" means what exactly?  Did you `sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop` to add a second desktop to your existing system (selected at login), reboot and install a new version in another partition thus now have two versions selected at boot time?  Telling us if you're using the HWE (5.3) kernel & stack *or* general kernel (4.15) & stack might also help  (`uname -r` will tell you the kernel running)